# How to lock the camera on X and Z axis, even though it is locked to a cube's rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the cube moves in the space, the camera follows it, because I made the camera a child of the cube. When the cube rotates in the Y direction (using player input), the camera does too. That is expected.

However, when the cube falls off a plane (it has rigid body physics), it rotates because of gravity (which is something I want), but the camera does too, because they are linked. How can I make the camera stuck in the X and Z directions?

This is how I control the cube's rotation:

```
float h = rotationSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
transform.Rotate(0, h, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Balto for the edit suggestion!

Comment: Create another object and attach to it and update its location as the cube location.

Comment: If the cube flips upside down because it fell what should happen to the camera?.